# How to call CUDA functions outside main()?

Tags: cuda, program-entry-point, nvidia

I'm very new to CUDA programming and have NOT had a hard time setting it all up. I'm using the driver API, i've modified the compilation workflow and all of my learning kernels and host programs work great. I'm learning directly from the cuda source samples as the SDK rely mostly on them. Everything is just perfect.

But i'm trying to extend my programs from the classic console example to a GUI and i am having a hard time calling any cuda function outside the classic main() function. I'm under Win32 and any call outside main() results in an "access violation", calling kernels or device query functions inside main() works ok, the gui program works ok too. This happends with all the API calls including cuInit(), so, making contexts current, pushing and popping contexts are not posible. If you take a look at the SDK examples, all of them are coded within main().

Does anyone have a clue about this issue? Does this happends to you as well? How to fix it?

Thank you very much for your comments in advance.

INFO:

- CUDA SDK version: 4.0
- Device: GeForce GTS 450 (GF106), Device Capability 2.1
- Win32 platform (Win7 x64 with WOW64).
- CUDA Driver API
- Host program made with the D programming language.

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of programs that use CUDA entirely outside main, the problem is more likely to be that your program is written in D and not C/C++. That's not to say it can't work (I've never used D) but you will need to remember that you are calling into a C API and that C is unmanaged.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually CUDA in D works just like in C because D is C ABI compatible: http://www.d-programming-language.org/abi.html

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that all my console programs work perfectly outside main and from other threads.

The problem is when building GUI binaries and so i thought it could be something with Win32 but it seems it's a library that i'm using (DFL, D Forms Library) that wraps all the Win32 stuff.
Not 100% sure about this, that's why i was asking about CUDA and Win32. Are there any examples of cuda with win32 gui out there?